# D naming conventions: How is Phobos organized?

Tags: d, phobos

I'm making my own little library of handy functions and I'm trying to follow Phobos's naming convention but I'm getting really confused. How do I know where things would fit?

#### Example:

If there was a function like `foldRight` in Phobos (basically `reduce` in the reverse direction), which module would I find it in?

I can think of several:

- `std.algorithm`: Because it's expressing an algorithm
- `std.array`: Because I'm likely going to use it on arrays
- `std.container`: Because it's used on containers, rather than single objects
- `std.functional`: Because it's used mainly in functional programming
- `std.range`: Because it operates on ranges as well

but I have no idea which one would be a good choice -- I could give a convincing argument for at least 3 of them.

What's the convention?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- `std.algorithm`: yep and you can implement it like reduce!fun(retro(r))

  this module specifies algorithms that run on sequences
- `std.array`: no because it can also run on other ranges

  these are helper functions that run only on build-in arrays
- `std.container`: no because it doesn't define a data structure (like a treeset)

  this defines data structures that are not build in into the language (for now a linked list, a binary tree and a deterministic array in terms of memory management)
- `std.functional`: no because it doesn't operate on a function but on a range

  this one takes a function and returns a different one
- `std.range`: no because it doesn't define a range or provide a different way to iterate over one

the lack of a clear structure is one of my gripes with the phobos library TBH but really reading the first paragraph of the docs should tell you quite a bit of where to put the function

Comment: +1 I **really** didn't expect to get back sensible explanations, but they seem to make sense (for the most part anyway). Thanks!